# Splitting the exact sequence of the idele class group.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In my  understanding, for a number field $K$, one can identify $K^{\times}$ with a subring of $\mathbb{A}_K$ (the adele ring), and then define the idele class group as $$0 \longrightarrow K^{\times} \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_{K}^{\times} \longrightarrow C_K \longrightarrow 0  ,$$
Are there any conditions on $K$ that will make this exact sequence split?

Thank you

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120585